# proper bpy.ops context setup in a plugin

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

How can I properly set up context in plugins?

I am importing Digital Terrain Models using a python plugin.

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DTM)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(add_to_menu)
```

I get the following error.

> C_dict, C_exec, C_undo = BPyOpsSubModOp._parse_args(args)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.67\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 142, in _parse_args raise ValueError("1-3 args execution context is supported") ValueError: 1-3 args execution context is supported

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which addon is that? If it isn't the "HiRISE DTM" one, please give a link to the full source code.

Comment: This looks more like a bug report then a question.

Comment: Maybe it's something in add_to_menu, trying to call an operator with incorrect arguments.

Comment: try:<br/>
            dtm = bpy.ops.import_img.load(self,context,filepath=self.filepath,scale=self.scale,bin_mode=self.bin_mode, cropVars=False,)<br/>
        except ValueError:<br/>
            print("location: <unknown location> -1")<br/>

Comment: You don't need `self` and `context` when calling an operator. Those first two argument positions are reserved for execution context.

Comment: bpy.ops has been updated since last try.<br/>
it seems to be an incorrect file location.<br/>
<br/>
using:<br/>
filepath = bpy.path.ensure_ext(filepath, filename_ext)<br/>
bpy.ops throws:<br/>
location: <unknown location> -1<br/>

Comment: @AshleyDuhn stop using the html break tag, they get converted to readable characters. Stackexchange uses markdown http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to help markup your text, read that link -- it's great.

Comment: the functions require the argument in a variable=value syntax like: `bpy.ops.mesh.decimate(ratio=0.18)` if I try `bpy.ops.mesh.decimate(0.18)` I get that 1-3 params error too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When calling an operator with `self` and `context`, I get the exact same error message:

```
ValueError: 1-3 args execution context is supported
```

The first 3 arguments are reserved for optional arguments. From Blender API [documentation](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.html#keywords-and-positional-arguments) on running an operator:

> For calling operators keywords are used for operator properties and positional arguments are used to define how the operator is called.
>
> There are 3 optional positional arguments (documented in detail below).
>
> ```
> bpy.ops.test.operator(override_context, execution_context, undo)
> ```
>
> - override_context
> - dict type execution_context - string (enum)
> - undo - boolean
>
> Each of these arguments is optional, but must be given in the order above.

In short, calling an operator with `self` and `context` as the first two arguments is wrong, and maybe the cause of the error message you've shown.

Comment: you're right. so using bpy.ops.import_img.load(self, with proper context would return MESH in the best of cases

Comment: I got this error when I had the syntax: `bpy.ops.object.join(obj2)` and resolved it by removing `obj2`, so just: `bpy.ops.object.join()` I thought the second object to be joined to the first but it turns out the join operator uses *selected* objects and an *active* object... it does not expect objects to be passed as arguments. Makes sense once you know. (Just posting this example in case it helps someone with a similar problem.)

Comment: However... the join operator *can* accept a copy of the scene context! `ctx = bpy.context.copy()` then `join(ctx)` assuming the selected objects and active object in the context are valid. I don't know the details of why this works, but [here's the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13991/2952) that demonstrates it. [The manual](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.join) currently doesn't explicitly mention any ability of `join()` to accept arguments though.

Comment: I found that the functions require the argument in a variable=value syntax like: `bpy.ops.mesh.decimate(ratio=0.18)` if I try `bpy.ops.mesh.decimate(0.18)` I get that 1-3 params error too, I dont know if this is like that only on newer blender versions, mine is 2.93.4