# combine objects by name in scene into one object

Tags: python, scripting, objects, bmesh

In my scene, I have multiple objects with the following names:

```
Verts
Verts.001
Verts.002
Verts.003
Verts.004
```

I want to combine all of these objects into one mesh which I can then export out as an stl. For what it's worth, the objects are just point clouds, with no face or edge information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `startswith()` function to select all the objects that stqrts with `Verts` and join them into one object :

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
for o in objects:
    if obj.name.startswith("Verts") :
        obj.select = True
bpy.ops.object.join()
```

Comment: the joined object doesn't show up in the scene though

Comment: I changed some of the code such that it works for me, based off of responses to this question

http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/how-to-join-objects-with-python