# creating two groups of joined objects using python

Tags: python, objects

I am trying to create multiple joined groups using [this answer to an already existing question.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13991/54256)

I am reading some coordinates from a file, creating spheres at those coordinates, and assigning a material of a certain color depending on the index. I would like to join together the spheres that have the same color.

Below is a minimal reproducible code:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

coords = np.loadtxt('coordinates.dat')

# 0 (A)
matBlue = bpy.data.materials.new(name="blue")
matBlue.diffuse_color = (0,0,1)
# 1 (B)
matRed = bpy.data.materials.new(name="red")
matRed.diffuse_color = (1,0,0)

materialColors = {0:matBlue, 1:matRed}

spheres = [[],[]]
count = 0     
for coord in coordinates:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(coord[0],coord[1],coord[2]), size=0.5)
    name = 'sphere' + str(count)
    bpy.context.active_object.name = name
    currentSphere = bpy.data.objects[name]
    currentSphere.data.materials.append(materialColors[count%2])
    spheres[count%2].append(currentSphere)
    count += 1

# join spheres
scene = bpy.context.scene

for i in range(2):
    ctx = bpy.context.copy()
    ctx['selected_objects'] = spheres[i]
    ctx['active_object'] = spheres[i][0]
    ctx['selected_editable_bases'] = [scene.object_bases[ob.name] for ob in spheres[i]]
    bpy.ops.object.join(ctx)
```

However, when I do this, I end up with red spheres joined, and the blue spheres are not joined. What am I doing wrong?

**Note: In reality, I have 8 groups instead of 2. Hence the for loop at the end.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Beware the naming system**

There is an issue with this part of your code, I've added a print statement boolean  if the object you have chosen as currentSphere is also the newly created sphere.  `bpy.data.objects["sphere0"]` will always be the first object created with this name. Running again with any objects with the same name existing, will give somewhat unpredictable results.

```
for coord in coords:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(coord[0],coord[1],coord[2]), size=0.5)
    name = 'sphere' + str(count)
    bpy.context.active_object.name = name

    currentSphere = bpy.data.objects[name]
    print(currentSphere is bpy.context.active_object)
```

could use something like below, where the `currentSphere` will be the newly created object, but may not end up with the name you choose. (To make sure it has unique name would need to check and rename/remove others)

```
for coord in coords:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(location=(coord[0],coord[1],coord[2]), size=0.5)
    name = 'sphere' + str(count)
    currentSphere = bpy.context.active_object
    currentSphere.name = name
    currentSphere.data.materials.append(materialColors[count%2])
    spheres[count%2].append(currentSphere)
    count += 1
```

I also contend in this case can set context, rather than overriding.

```
for i in range(2):
    for o in scene.objects:
        o.select = o in spheres[i]   
    scene.objects.active = spheres[i][0]
    bpy.ops.object.join()
```

**Bmesh approach**

Another suggestion would be scrapping the primitive add and join operators altogether and use `bmesh` to create spheres at coordinates.  Test script, creates two bmeshes for odd and even coordinates, and writes the first to active object's mesh.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

coords = [(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0)]
bmeshes = [bmesh.new(), bmesh.new()]
for i, coord in enumerate(coords):
    bmesh.ops.create_uvsphere(bmeshes[i % 2],
        u_segments = 16,
        v_segments = 8,
        matrix=Matrix.Translation(coord), 
        diameter=0.5)

# for example sake to mesh onto active_ob
me = bpy.context.object.data
bmeshes[0].to_mesh(me)
me.update()
for bm in bmeshes:
    bm.free()
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and pointing out the possibility to use `bmesh`.