Join objects via script Blender 3.5: context is incorrect
I keep getting context is invalid error, when trying to merge all meshes in the scene
### sources: 
### - base code generated by ChatGPT.
### - merging code from: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13986/how-to-join-objects-with-python

import bpy
import os

# Set the directory containing the .3ds files
input_folder = "C:\Database\ModelDB\furniture"
output_folder = "C:\Database\ModelDB\furniture"

# Ensure the output directory exists
if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
  os.makedirs(output_folder)

# Loop through all the .3ds files in the input folder
for file_name in os.listdir(input_folder):
  if file_name.endswith(".3ds"):
    # Full path to the .3ds file
    input_file = os.path.join(input_folder, file_name)
    
    # Define output .fbx file path
    output_file = os.path.join(output_folder, file_name.replace(".3ds", ".fbx"))
    
    # Clear any previous data in Blender
    bpy.ops.wm.read_homefile(use_empty=True)
    
    # Import the .3ds file
    bpy.ops.import_scene.autodesk_3ds(filepath=input_file)
    
    # Select and join all objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    count = 0
    # obs = []
    for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
      if ob.type == 'MESH':
        # obs.append(ob)
        ob.select_set(state=True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
        count += 1

    if (count > 1):
      # with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=obs[0], selected_objects=obs):
      bpy.ops.object.join()
    
    # Export to .fbx
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=output_file, use_selection=False)
    
    print(f"Converted {input_file} to {output_file}")

print("Conversion completed.")

The line that crashes is bpy.ops.object.join() with the following error
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.join.poll() failed, context is incorrect
I also tried the commented lines with the ops array, but I can't get it to work. When I hit Ctrl+J in the scene window, at the point where the script crashes, it merges correctly and the objects seem to be selected correctly (All objects are selected and I have an active obejct).

What am I doing wrong?
EDIT: running bpy.ops.object.join() from the python console after the crash also works. Is this some kind of async error, that the selection or something like that hasn't finished yet??

Was this code generated by AI? If so you should provide attribution

Any wrong context errors in lines that uses blender tools can be fixed by supplying context "overrides"
for example, for any lines like
bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=1.16208, offset_pct=0, segments=15, affect='EDGES')

or
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')

or in your case
bpy.ops.object.join()

can be written as follows
override = context_override()
bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(override ,offset=1.16208, offset_pct=0, segments=15, affect='EDGES')

override = context_override()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(override ,use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')

override = context_override()
bpy.ops.object.join(override )

where context_override() function typically does the following job:
def context_override():
    for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    override = bpy.context.copy()
                    override['area'] = area
                    override['region'] = region
                    override['space_data'] = area.spaces.active
                    override['edit_object'] = bpy.context.edit_object
                    return override
                    break


override becomes the first argument passed in this case. However post blender 3.2 theres a simpler way of providing context overrides.
example:
area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"][0]
 
with bpy.context.temp_override(area=area):
    bpy.ops.object.join()



The correct override syntax for object.join is :
with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=obs[0], selected_editable_objects=obs):
    bpy.ops.object.join()

For reference the point of the override is so that you don't need to worry about selecting the objects nor making an object active.
    # Select and join all objects
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    count = 0
    # obs = []
    for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
      if ob.type == 'MESH':
        # obs.append(ob)
        ob.select_set(state=True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
        count += 1

    if (count > 1):
      # with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=obs[0], selected_objects=obs):
      bpy.ops.object.join()

Becomes
    obs = [o for o in bpy.context.scene.objects if o.type == "MESH"]
    if len(obs) > 1:
        with bpy.context.temp_override(active_object=obs[0], selected_editable_objects=obs):
            bpy.ops.object.join()

